# Clojure: Maintain purity with Java Interop limitations

Tags: java, clojure, functional-programming

I have a snippet of Clojure code that follows the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) as defined in a third-party Java library that looks like the following:

```
(defrecord RecordHandler []
  RecordListener
  (onMsg [this msg] (getValue msg)))

(defn read
  [file]
  (let [decoder (Decode.)
        broadcaster (MsgBroadcaster. decoder)
        handler (RecordHandler.)]
    (.addListener broadcaster handler)
    (.run broadcaster file)))
```

I want to be able to collect the results of each record when `onMsg` is called. The major limitation I have is that `Decode`, `MsgBroadcaster` and the `RecordListener` interface are all defined by the third-party library and the `onMsg` returns `void`.

How do I collect the values of each broadcast to `RecordHandler` while still remaining pure? My current solution involves passing a vector reference to the initialization of `RecordHandler` and using `alter` and `conj`, but that is modifying a reference, which seems to violate the idea of not modifying external state.

```
(defrecord RecordHandler [memo]
  RecordListener
  (onMsg [this msg] 
    (dosync
      (alter memo conj (getValue msg))))

(defn read
  [file]
  (let [decoder (Decode.)
        broadcaster (MsgBroadcaster. decoder)
        memo (ref [])
        handler (RecordHandler. memo)]
    (.addListener broadcaster handler)
    (.run broadcaster file)))
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but `alter` has to be called from within a transaction, and I do not see one in your code.

Comment: you are correct. this was hand-written to simplify for the example's sake. added it to avoid confusion. thanks.

Comment: Ok, but now it looks like you define an implementation for the `dosync` method of the `RecordListener` interface ?

Comment: Given the constraints that you describe, I don't see an approach that doesn't involve some sort of mutable state. What you're doing sounds perfectly OK to me.

Comment: @nha fixed again, thanks.